# Prove that Archimedean Property implies that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Problem:**

> Prove that Archimedean Property implies that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0.$

I am very curious how to prove this.  To start off, we assume the Archimedean Property, or there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that, $\dfrac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, for any natural number $n$.  But, from there I am simply lost.  Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

What does it mean for $a_n$ to satisfies $lim_{ n\to \infty} a_n = 0$?

It means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N$ such that, if $m>N$ then

$|a_m - 0| < \epsilon$

Back to our case:

Here $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then

$lim_{ n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$ reads:

For every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $N$ such that, if $m>N$ then

$| \frac{1}{m}| = \frac{1}{m} < \epsilon$.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I think here you are assuming that limit of 1/n then proving the Archimedean property.  I'm thinking of assuming the Archimedean Property then deducing that 1/n tends to 0 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: I didnt deduce anything. If you assume Archimedian property then for every $\epsilon$ there is a N such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$ and since $\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{N}$ for every $m>N$ then we deduce your limit.

Comment: now if I wanted to show the converse of this, which is that the limit implies Archimedean how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \not= 0$, then by definition of limits, we have have:

> $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists n \geq N$ for which $\displaystyle \left| \frac{1}{n}-0 \right| > \epsilon$

Since $n \geq N$ implies $1/n \leq 1/N$, the above actually implies that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{N} \geq \left| \frac{1}{n}-0 \right| > \epsilon$, which in turn implies that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\displaystyle N<\epsilon$, which contradicts the Archimedean property of real numbers since $\epsilon$ is a real number larger than any positive integer.

Comment: And of course, since it contradicts the Archimedean property, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \not= 0$ is impossible, and hence $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$.